# How to round up to the higher 10 in C#?

Tags: c#

I have to write a program at school that allows the user to input a 7-digits of a `GTIN-8` barcode and calculate check digit. To calculate the check digit the seven input numbers are multiplied by 3, 1, 3, 1 etc.

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    //Convert String to Character
    ch = gtinNum[i];

    //Convert Character to Integer
    number = Convert.ToInt32(ch);
    product = number * weights[i];
    total = total + product;
}//end for loop
```

After that, the total is taken away from the nearest higher ten. For example if the total was 43 then it would be 50-43.
In the simplest way possible, how do I round up to the higher ten?

Comment: How about using modulus to get the value down to between 0 and 10 to begin with, and simply subtract it from 10? `10 - (total % 10)` ?

Comment: You can actually look at what it actually _means_ to subtract from the next highest multiple of ten. And then look whether there's a built-in operator to do the same.

Comment: Using pure `int` math it's `total / 10 * 10 + 10`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Math.Ceiling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx), you just need to divide by ten first and multiply by 10 afterwards. Divide by 10.0 to avoid integer division(`Math.Ceiling` takes `double`):

```
int num = 43;
int nextHigherTen = (int)Math.Ceiling(num / 10.0) * 10;
```

This "rounds" 41-50 up to 50. If you want it from 40-49 you could use this:

```
int nextHigherTen = (int)Math.Ceiling((num + 1) / 10.0) * 10;
```